# Android In app purchase : Purchase done but content not devlivered

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In the Android app , signature verification is done in local server . Considet this case :

If I make an in app purchase , cash is debited  for the item . But due to some error (local server not responding or no netwrok connectivity),  content is not delivered, as a result confirmNotification is not called . In that case google market should send the IN_APP_NOTIFY again. But this(IN_APP_NOTIFY) may not come in certain cases . So I need to do the verification manually and send the confirmNotification(). So can if I do it manually with latest stored **notifyId**  , is it Okay ?  But still we need to send a string array of notifyId in 
*confirmNotifications(int startId, String[] notifyIds)*

Any idea how to do it manually??

Comment: Not sure, but here's another tutorial for perspective: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html 8-)